# NestedScrollView inside fragment not programatically scrolling

Tags: android-studio, android-nestedscrollview

I have a tablayout with a viewpager2 and FragmentStateAdapter. I have 3 tabs, each with a NestedScrollView that wraps a Linear Layout:

```xml
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

            /* ... */

       </LinearLayout>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

**When I switch between the tabs in the tablayout, the scrollview does not start at the top. In the onViewCreated() method of each Fragment for the viewPager, I added the following lines, however the scrollview still does not scroll to the top, it starts where it was left off.**

```java
public static class MyFragment extends Fragment {

        private NestedScrollView scrollView;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                                 @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
        }

        @Override
        public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            scrollView = view.findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
            scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, 0);
        }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onViewCreated` is only called when the `Fragment`s are first created. A `ViewPager` does not change the state of the `Fragment`s. You can think of the hidden `Fragments` being stored, visible, to the sides of the currently visible `Fragment`.

I accomplished by setting up a callback when the `TabLayout` changes. The `TabLayout` is where the listener for this is. You can then have it call a callback method in your `FragmentPagerAdapter`. In each `Fragment`, you should implement a method that returns a callback. In the `FragmentPagerAdapter`, use the `getItem(int position)` to store the callback from the `Fragment` in a `Map`. The callback method in the adapter takes the position from the `TabLayout`

First, in your Fragments, give them a method that returns some kind of callback (I used a `Runnable`) that will be called from the adapter.

```java
public class PlaceHolderFragment extends Fragment {

...

    public Runnable getOnTabChangedListener() {
        return new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, 0);
            }
        };
    }

...

}
```

Then, in your `FragmentPagerAdapter` (I called mine `SectionsPagerAdapter`), store the callbacks in a map in the `getItem()` method, and then add a custom callback.

```java
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    ...

    HashMap<Integer, Runnable> tabChangedCallbacks = new HashMap<>();

    ...

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
        tabChangedCallbacks.put(position, fragment.getOnTabChangedListener());
        return fragment;
    }

    public void onTabChanged(int position) {
        tabChangedCallbacks.get(position).run();
    }

    ...

}
```

In your activity that contains the TabLayout, you will want to call `addOnTabSelectedListener()` on the TabLayout in the `onCreate()` method.

```java
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ...

    final SectionsPagerAdapter sectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(this, getSupportFragmentManager());
    final ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(sectionsPagerAdapter);
    TabLayout tabs = findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    tabs.addOnTabSelectedListener(
            new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(viewPager) {
                @Override
                public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                    super.onTabSelected(tab);
                    sectionsPagerAdapter.onTabChanged(tab.getPosition());
                }
            });

    ...

}
```

### EDIT

The principle is the same, but for this to work using `ViewPager2` and `FragmentStateAdapter`, you will need the follow changes:

The `Fragment` stays the same.

The adapter is the same, functionally, with some updated methods:

```java
public class SectionsStateAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter {

    HashMap<Integer, Runnable> tabChangedCallbacks = new HashMap<>();

    ...

    public void onTabChanged(int position) {
        tabChangedCallbacks.get(position).run();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment createFragment(int position) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
        tabChangedCallbacks.put(position, fragment.getOnTabChangedListener());
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    ...
}
```

The activity changes the most:

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ...

        final SectionsStateAdapter sectionsStateAdapter = new SectionsStateAdapter(this);
        final ViewPager2 viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(sectionsStateAdapter);
        TabLayout tabs = findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        // connect the TabLayout to the ViewPager2
        new TabLayoutMediator(tabs, viewPager, new TabLayoutMediator.TabConfigurationStrategy() {
            @Override
            public void onConfigureTab(@NonNull TabLayout.Tab tab, int position) {
                // set tab text, etc
            }
        }).attach();
        // set the change listener on the ViewPager2
        viewPager.registerOnPageChangeCallback(new ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                super.onPageSelected(position);
                sectionsStateAdapter.onTabChanged(position);
            }
        });

        ...

    }
}
```

Note that the only real change is that the ViewPager2 doesn't need the TabLayout to handle the page change. You could still use `TabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener()` if you wanted, but you would have to implement your own `TabLayout.OnTabSelecterListener` since `TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener` doesn't work with `ViewPager2`.

For example:

```java
tabs.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                sectionsStateAdapter.onTabChanged(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution from @star4z should work, but there is an easier option. What you could do instead, use `FragmentPagerAdapter` for this and set it's behavior to `BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT`.

Every time, you change your tab, `onResume` will be called and there you can call your `scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, 0);`

```
public class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
...
        public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm, BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT);
        }
...
    
}
```

And then in your `Fragment`:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

...

    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, 0);
    }

...

}
```

Comment: the only problem is that I am using viewPager2 with FragmentStateAdapter. How would you do it with for that?